# Tests finish with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, macos, unit-testing, cmake, clion

I'm a CS student and one of the classes I'm taking this semester requires me to complete different assignments (in C++) and then test them with unit-tests written by our professor.

[Link to the repository with tests and the skeleton of the exercises](https://gitlab.com/agh-jimp2/exercises)

All of the tests form la1 worked just fine. Sadly most of them stopped working just as I started testing code from lab2 exercises. All the tests print the same message to the console:

> Running main() from gtest_main.cc
>
> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Today, after I've completed the lab2->greatestproduct exercise

> Given an array of integers, write a function, maxProductFinderK, that can be obtained from any k integers in the array.

I checked all of the tests by hand and the result I've gotten were all correct so I don't think my code is the real issue here.

Is there anything that I could double-check to solve this problem? So far I've tried:

- creating new CMakeLists.txt file (I don't think that's the problem since I use a template to create them)
- cloning the repository with exercises again
- Using different solutions just to make sure the code itself is not the problem

I'm running all the tests in CLion (with the latest update) on MacOS 10.13.3 if that's relevant.

// Edit: just as requested I added the code here in case the link will stop working.

Solution to the assignment:

```
int GreatestProduct(const std::vector<int> &numbers, int k) {
if ( numbers.size() > 0) {
    std::vector<int> largestK = numbers;
    std::sort(largestK.begin(), largestK.end());

    if (k == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (k == 1) {
        return largestK.at(largestK.size() - 1);
    }

    largestK.erase(largestK.begin(), largestK.end() - (k)); // remove all but k largest elements

    std::vector<int> smallestK = numbers;
    std::sort(smallestK.begin(), smallestK.end());
    smallestK.erase(smallestK.begin(),
                    smallestK.begin() + k - (k % 2));  // remove all but k-(k%2) smallest elements

    int mustContain = (k % 2) * (largestK.at(0) - 1) + 1;

    //make sure that largestK and smallestK are the same size
    if (k % 2 != 0) {
        largestK.erase(largestK.begin());
    }

    std::vector<int> final;
    int currentLargest = 0;
    int currentSmallest = 0;
    int greatestProduct = 1;

    while (currentLargest + currentSmallest < k - (k % 2)) {
        int firstOption = largestK.at(currentLargest) * largestK.at(currentLargest + 1);
        int secondOption = smallestK.at(currentSmallest) * smallestK.at(currentSmallest + 1);
        if (mustContain * firstOption > mustContain * secondOption) {
            final.push_back(firstOption);
            currentLargest += 2;
        } else {
            final.push_back(secondOption);
            currentSmallest += 2;
        }
    }

    for (int element : final) {
        greatestProduct *= element;
    }
    return greatestProduct;
} else {
    return 0;
} }
```

First out of 3 test. This one's the easiest since it always assumes that k = 2 and it doesn't test negative integers.

```
#include <GreatestProduct.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <MemLeakTest.h>
#include <StringUtility.h>

using TestParam = std::pair<std::pair<std::vector<int>, int>, int>;

class GreatestProductOfStep1Tests : public ::testing::TestWithParam<TestParam>, MemLeakTest {

};

TEST_P(GreatestProductOfStep1Tests, GreatestProductOfPositiveNumbersNfixedTo2ShouldReturnExpectedResult) {
  const TestParam &p = GetParam();
  int expected = p.second;
  const std::vector<int> &numbers = p.first.first;
  int N = p.first.second;
  EXPECT_EQ(expected, GreatestProduct(numbers, N))
            << "Did call GreatestProductOf(" << utility::ToString<int>(numbers) << ", " << N << ")\n";
}

std::vector<TestParam> greatest_product_test_positive_n_eq_2_data{
    {{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 2}, 12},
    {{{6, 6, 6}, 2}, 36},
    {{{9, 8, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 5, 10}, 2}, 90},
    {{{17, 5, 9, 1000, 15689, 57, 89, 10, 89, 283, 197, 0, 0, 132, 45, 78, 18, 15, 89,
       19203, 98, 14, 78, 45, 35, 23, 24, 25, 46, 45, 756, 7567, 123, 890, 99, 98, 51,
       991, 9123, 8912, 89534, 8923, 1823, 7385, 91, 1748, 1, 1, 893, 2813,
       1381, 23, 563, 645, 24, 24, 51, 839, 38, 34, 35, 123, 324, 9283, 22, 19}, 2}, 1719321402},
    {{{1, 1}, 2}, 1},
    {{{0, 1}, 2}, 0},
    {{{3789, 999}, 2}, 3785211}};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(GreatestProductOfStep1Tests,
                        GreatestProductOfStep1Tests,
                        ::testing::ValuesIn(greatest_product_test_positive_n_eq_2_data));
```

Comment: If `k >= numbers.size()` or `k == 1`, you will overflow the vector. That could cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: I completely forgot about those two cases. I've already added them but sadly all tests still fail (first one assumes that k = const and it's equal to 2)

Comment: Don't post links to external pages that will soon disappear.  The question will then become useless once those links become non-functional.  But some other advice -- 1) Debug your program -- don't just post it, say it fails in some way, and then have someone here debug it for you.  There is a link "I downvoted because ..." that explicitly has the example of the poster not debugging their code.  2) Using `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` would have pointed out any boundary access violations when using vector (a `std::out_of_range` exception would be thrown).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've already updated my solution with the vector::at(). It didn't solve my problem but after running the debugger it seems that a memory leak is the problem here. ("memory allocated at <adress> of size 56 was not properly freed")